How to use Django's {% static %} tag inside background image URL of inline CSS?
While i'm working on a django project, in my html page there is div containing background image. I'll provide the code snippet below.
Here we can see a gif file which I want to put in a  {% static %} tag. But it is not working.
chatgpt provide me as a solution.
which is not working. "at-rule or selector expected" this error occurs
While i'm working on a django project, in my html page there is div containing background image.

It's very easy to do. I personally don't like rendering css like a djnago template where you can call statics, so I use really static css and only specify dynamic variables in inline-css, directly in the template:
{# somethere in your django template #}
{% load static %}
<div class="myclass" styles=background-image:url({% static "path/to/myimage.png" %});">

